# Reset Reactive Form Fields

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have around **20 textboxes** and **one checkbox**.

So wherever users check/uncheck the checkbox whatever values inside those 20 textboxes should be reset.

Either 20 textboxes values should be submitted or a single checkbox value should be submitted.

Current Scenario
I am using `this.Myfrom.reset();` to reset all the fields and it is working.

But I don't want to reset one control value.

**Question**- Should I write 20 lines of codes by getting each control from the form array and reset the control values.

```
this.Myfrom.get('text1').reset();
```

and so on to 20th textbox just to skip only one field not to reset.

Is there any other way to do this. Or this approach is good.

Comment: You can use `pathValue` for that specific input after resetting all inputs. 
`this.myForm.reset()` clear all fields and then `this.myForm.patchValue({YourInput: 'YourValue'})`

Comment: But I am using ngFor for creating dynamic rows over the array of object in HTML table. So lets say if there are 10 rows generated how can I set the value after reset all the fields of a row.

Comment: then you can simple push value into your desired Index.

Comment: Ok. after reset all the fields, I a getting the value of element by using var test=((this.form.get('controls') as FormArray).at(index) as FormGroup).value; But it's now working. Any idea how to get the value of an element from formgroup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this :

```
this.yourForm.reset({
    email: this.yourForm.get('email').value, 
});
```

Code Will reset myForm but excludes email